# How to fix error No signature of method: build_9rfemhg4a5yc2kwb7aemx3270.android() is applicable for argument type

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, data-binding

I am trying to add databinding to my app.
But the error I am getting after I enable databinding is this:
**No signature of method: build_9rfemhg4a5yc2kwb7aemx3270.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_9rfemhg4a5yc2kwb7aemx3270$_run_closure1) values: [build_9rfemhg4a5yc2kwb7aemx3270$_run_closure1@6e3b0699]**

The part that causes the error is:

```
databinding {
   enabled = true
}
```

Removing this part causes the gradle to build properly. But that way I can't add databinding.

the build gradle is :

```
plugins {
   id 'com.android.application'
   id 'kotlin-android'
}

android {
   compileSdkVersion 30
   buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

   defaultConfig {
       applicationId "com.example.aboutme"
       minSdkVersion 19
       targetSdkVersion 30
       versionCode 1
       versionName "1.0"

       testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
   }

   buildTypes {
       release {
           minifyEnabled false
           proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-      rules.pro'
       }
   }
   databinding {
      enabled = true
   }
   compileOptions {
       sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
       targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
   }
   kotlinOptions {
       jvmTarget = '1.8'
   }
}

dependencies {

   implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
   implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
   implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
   implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
   implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
   testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
   androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
   androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer.
data'B'inding not data'b'inding

```
dataBinding {
  enabled = true
}
```